# What data structure should I use for this kind of data?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct, typedef

My data looks like this:

```
University {

    Society {

        LibrariesList 
            Library {

                Name: "Central Library"
                BuildingNumber: 23b
                Address {
                    Electronic Address: "blahblah blah"
                    Phone: 12345677
                    Street Address {
                        Num:4
                    }
                }
                Code:43

            }
        DepartmentsList:1

    }

}
```

I have to store it in my C program. I am a beginner in C and don't know which data structure to use for this kind of thing. So what data structure should I use?

Comment: can't you just store it in a dynamic array named libraries? what are you going to do with it after once yhou have the list?

Comment: Just showing the data format is not enough to decide what data structure to use. How the data will be used is equally or more important. How often are inserts done? How often are deletes done? How often are lookups done? Are the lookups consecutive or random? etc.

Comment: @kaylum seriously? Are you really going to talk to him about hashmaps, red-black trees etc. in C? He is a beginner. He is learning programming, not developing a scalable industry ready-app. So structures and vectors. And to answer your question in his behalf: the data will be used as a pretext to learn the basics of C.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
struct stradr
{
      int num;
};

struct add
{
      char electronicAddress[100];
      unsigned int phone;
      struct stradr streetAddress;
};

struct lib
{
      char name[100];
      char BuildingNo[5];
      struct add address;
};

struct libList
{
       struct lib library;
       int code;
};

struct scty
{
        struct libList librarieslist;
        int departList;
};

struct unvrsty
{
        struct scty society;
} university;
```

As of a data structure in c, I don't think that C can handle strings and Integers together. There might be better ways, but that would be too complicated to implement, considering you said that you are beginner :)

Comment: What makes `struct libList` a list?

Comment: @alk mainly because the library is under the heading librarieslist, Which I believe might be subjected to changes, so I assumed it to be one. Just a failsafe, although redundant.